# How to get list of all connected devices of wifi in Flutter Latest(3.0.1)?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have tried all dependencies like mdns 0.0.1, Wifi Plugin Info, and Network Plugin info but have not gotten the result. Is there any way to get all connected devices in with mac address & Name in flutter latest(3.0.1)

Comment: I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835616/flutter-dart-scan-local-network-to-get-ip-and-hostname-of-connected-devices), not sure if it fits your case.

Comment: Your answer doesn't match my question, I want to get a list of connected devices with device names, also I can attach a screenshot.   See carefully what I want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMzPy.png

Comment: @flutterdevloper i also stuck on getting hotspot list of connected devices in flutter

Comment: @flutterdeveloper if you find the solution of your question please guide us on this question please

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use
https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus

I can get the ssid name but everything else is null